# Чтение двоичных файлов

Tags: qt

Есть двоичный файл с известной структурой. Например, первые два байта содержат 4-х значное число (типа 2056), в просмотрщике это выглядит как "20 56". Подскажите, как средсвами qt прочитать хотя бы эти первые числа, ну или средствами C++.

Answer (score 3):

Интересно, что значит "двоичный файл" и "в просмотрщике это выглядит как "20 56"", что за просмотровщик? Вообще, мягко говоря, вариантов масса, на вскидку: `fopen+fread` (вообще из c), `istream` (из стандартной бибилиотеки c++).

Если нужно именно средствами Qt, то Вам сюда: [Класс QDataStream](http://qt-doc.ru/klass-qdatastream.html).

Answer (score 0):

На будущее: Qt имеет нереально крутую справку, и гугл о ней прекрасно знает: [пример](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdatastream.html)